# Xpath 2.0: Check the sequence of records in choice group

Tags: xml, xpath

I have this issue and it's very hard to me to solve it. Can you help me on this? Thank you all of you in advanced.
I have this schema:

```
    <submission>
        <sequence>
            <Header></Header>
            <Data>
                <Choice>
                    <Record1 maxOccurs="*">
                        <RecordType></RecordType>
                        <Content></Content>
                    </Record1>
                    <Record2 maxOccurs="*">
                        <RecordType></RecordType>
                        <Content></Content>
                    </Record2>
                    ...
                    <Record9 maxOccurs="*">
                        <RecordType></RecordType>
                        <Content></Content>
                    </Record9>
                </Choice>
            </Data>
            <Trailer></Trailer>     
        </sequence>
</submission>
```

And this is XML file:

```
<Submission>
    <Header>
        <Section>1</Section>
        <Rest>016CLAIMS042013080120130831</Rest>
    </Header>
    <Data>
        <Record1>
            <RecordType>1</RecordType>
            <Content>Record1</Content>
        </Record1>
        <Record1>
            <RecordType>1</RecordType>
            <Content>Record1</Content>
        </Record1>
        <Record2>
            <RecordType>2</RecordType>
            <Content>Record1</Content>
        </Record2>
        <Record3>
            <RecordType>3</RecordType>
            <Content>Record3</Content>
        </Record2>
        <Record5>
            <RecordType>5</RecordType>
            <Content>Record5</Content>
        </Record5>
        <Record4>
            <RecordType>4</RecordType>
            <Content>Record4</Content>
        </Record4>
        <Record4>
            <RecordType>6</RecordType>
            <Content>Record6</Content>
        </Record4>
    </Data>
    <Trailer>
        <Section>9</Section>
        <Rest>016CLAIMS042013080120130831</Rest>
    </Trailer>
</Submission>
```

You can see that the sequence of data records in this file is 1,2,3,5,4,6.
My problem is to write a XPath 2.0 query to validate this document if the sequence is correct. The sequence should be 1,2,3,4,5,6 so this file is incorrect. 
Please help me to write a XPath 2.0 query to check this.
Thank you very much again.

Comment: So you want a single self-contained XPath expression that does your schema validation? Wow!

Comment: Hi Marcus, yes. User can pass wrong format file to server. I am using BizTalk to validate this file. So this is a case.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your schema language. An intuitive reading suggests to me that the data element can consist of either lots of Record1 elements, or lots of Record2 elements, or lots of Record3 elements, ..., but not a mixture of these.

If the ONLY thing you want to check in the XPath is that the sequence of RecordType values is the sequence of natural numbers, then you can write

```
not((//RecordType)[number(.) != position()])
```

Comment: Hi Michael, thank you for your answer. But yes, Record1, Record2, etc can be appear many times. But I need to check if Record2 appears only after all record1, Record3 appears only after all Record3, etc.

Comment: Then I think it would be a good idea to give a more precise formulation of exactly what your XPath expression should do. It might also be helpful to say more about the constraints. I don't know Biztalk, but last time I heard it only supported XPath 1.0?